# Calculate the number of sides of a regular polygon ABCDE

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles

For reference:
Since the regular polygon ABCDE, calculate the number of sides
knowing that AC and BE forms an angle whose measurement is $135^{\circ}$.

My progress:

I found that there is an isosceles triangle

I drew some auxiliary lines but I can't find the relationship

[image]

by geogebra:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$45^{\circ}=\measuredangle EMC=\measuredangle EBC+\measuredangle ACB=\frac{1}{2}\left(\widehat{EC}+\widehat{AB}\right)=\frac{3}{2}\widehat{AB}=\frac{3}{2}\cdot\frac{360^{\circ}}{n}$$

Comment: This is a nice answer!  Am voting for it!

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg  Thanks a lot for the help. Very good solution

Comment: @peta arantes  Because $\widehat{EC}=2\widehat{AB}.$

Answer (score 1):

[image]

There are $12$ sides.${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

$\overline{v_1 v_3}$ and $\overline{v_2v_5}$ form an angle of $135^\circ.$

Similarly,

$\overline{v_1 v_3}$ and $\overline{v_2v_{11}}$ form an angle of $135^\circ.$

The angle at $v_2$ is thus $180^\circ- 2 \cdot 45^\circ=90^\circ$ so ${v_2 v_5v_8 v_{11}}$ is a square.

Each pair of vertices on the square bookends two additional vertices belonging to the regular polygon we are interested in.  So the total number of vertices (and thus sides) is $12.$

Comment: You are welcome